# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Automation server can't create object

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Trying to get UserName and used code below to obtine this. Note if I Call the function from button it shows correct user name in pupup window.

```
<body onload = "GetUserName();">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function GetUserName() {
         var WinNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
        //alert(WinNetwork.UserName);
         var userName = WinNetwork.UserName;
        //var userName = 'test';
        document.getElementById('label1').innerHTML = userName;
    }
    </script>
    <form runat="server">    
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfUserName" runat="server" value="a"/>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phLabelUser" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

in code behind I create label to show it but intention is to use hidden controller

```
    Label label= new Label();
    label.ID = "lbl1";
    label.Text = "test -> " + hfUserName.Value;
    phLabelUser.Controls.Add(label);
```

I Enabled the following settings in IE so there is no security issues the site is on intranet.

```
Run ActiveX controls and plug-ins
Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe.
```

Why this would create an error in debuger?

"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Automation server can't create object"

Comment: I would suggest using Server side method to access this data.  Consider using DirectorySearcher to get access to the UserName from AD

Comment: I'f you're open to this I can provide a code sample